# Mathematical cross product in java

Tags: java, math

Is there a code for a mathematical vector/cross product in Java ? Or does it need to be explicitly coded ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. A cross product of what?

Comment: What do you mean by cross product ?

Comment: you mean cross product of 2 vectors as in Physics

Comment: Possibly he just means the * operator.

Comment: I just remembered my maths classes and there's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: What class is this, a vector class? If so + also does not work for vector classes but it is likely to have .add() and .cross() methods

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the cross product of vectors, the answer is no. You can easily code this yourself though.

There are implementations outside of the standard Java API, for example in the [Apache Commons libraries](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/threed/Vector3D.html#crossProduct%28org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.Vector).

Answer (score 3):

The Java3D graphics library has a [Vector3d](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Vector3d.html#cross%28javax.vecmath.Vector3d,%20javax.vecmath.Vector3d%29) class, and that has a `cross` method. That is an official Sun/Oracle library.

Comment: +1 for finding a method in an official library.